# about the position of adverb `ever`

Tags: adverbs, clauses

A example:

> I don't think I'll ever go there

and the alternative:

> I don't think I'll go there ever

And I wanna know is there any difference between both sentences?

Furthermore, I don't know whether `ever` modifies `think` or `go`?

Comment: The construction *I don't ever think I'll go there* would have ***ever*** modifying ***think*** (with the meaning ***I never think I will do that** = that's not what I ever think*, as opposed to ***I think I will never do that** = [I think] that's not what I will ever do*).

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+not+go+there+ever%2Cwill+not+ever+go+there&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20not%20ever%20go%20there%3B%2Cc0) showing that ***will not ever go there*** is a perfectly common sequence of words, but ***will not go there ever*** is too rare to even show on the chart.

Comment: ...and don't even think about *will go there **never*** as an alternative to *will **never** go there.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are roughly the same. To my ear the "ever" in the second version is a little more forceful.

"ever" modifies "go" in both sentences.

Comment: The only reason I can see for saying that the second version is "more forceful" is that it's "**marked**" ("non-standard", not what we'd expect). When a competent native speaker uses such a "marked" form, we can *almost always* assume he intends some different kind of meaning. Often, the intended different meaning is contextually obvious (but it could be just about *anything*). But if there's no obvious alternative meaning, the "default" is just ***non-standard phrasing conveys emphasis*** (if only because it forces the reader to pause and think "Why did he phrase it like that?").

Comment: (I can't upvote because of "They are roughly the same". They're not - the second version *very uncommon* by comparison with the first version, and it's that very fact that causes us to assign it a slightly different *meaning*.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The second is more unusual (as you have verified) and it's the rarity that makes me notice the "ever" and give it a little more weight. Nevertheless I think it reasonable to say they are "roughly the same". We can disagree.

Comment: I suppose really it's just the word "roughly" that bothers me here. Which makes little sense really, because I'd probably have been perfectly happy with *They **mean essentially** the same thing.* And I think the only reason I like that alternative is because whenever I write that myself, I'm always about to follow it up with a ***but...*** In this case, the big "but" being that there's a huge difference in prevalence for the two forms (which from my perspective is pretty much the only reason there's any difference in "meaning" anyway).

Comment: Why *ever* modify *go* in second sentence? Because it is closer to *go*? It's a rule?

Comment: @yixuan The "ever" modifies "go" because it's telling you something about how you go. In this case, it;s essentially "never" because of the "don't think". You could say " Think I will never go." Compare that structure to "I will go gracefully". There "gracefully" modifies "go". This is not a rule, nor is it about the placement of the words. It's about how the words work together in the sentence.